# Windows application + master web config + connection string

Tags: c#, .net, web-config, windows

How could I allow my windows applications to use the connection strings in master web config rather than individual app config files?

Comment: what you mean by *master web config*?

Comment: @rahul: I have created a web.config and hosted in the root of a web server which my published web applications use to get the connection strings. Whenever we have to change the passwords and add new connections, this method helps to make the changes at one stop.

Comment: @NagarajRaveendran Are you planning to run that Windows Application inside the server that Web Application is hosted?

Comment: @win: I have hosted the windows application(.exe) in the server where the  web applications are hosted and the users have the shortcut to it in their desktops.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

NO, AFAIK you can't do that. You use a `app.config` for a windows/Winform application and it can't access a `web.config` defined in another project.

You should be having a separate config file for your windows project. else, define that connection string in `machine.config` so that it can be shared by all your projects.